# android emulator eclipse quits application,

Tags: android, textview, integer, android-edittext

UPDATE*I have deleted the female, male buttons and added a checkbox as suggested but now its crashing again*. No syntax errors. WHY IS IT CRASHING??? Please help.

Here is the code:
I have a couple of problems with my code, I would really appreciate if you could help me out...

I have a USMC Initial Strenght test calculator, and it does not show me any syntax errors. The problem is when that after I input all the values in edittext, when I click calculate it crashes. So I realized, it has to do with the fact that I want the score that was calculated by one of the methods to be displayed in a textView, so I have to convert the textView to Integer right?
And I also want to display a text that says pass or fail in a different textview according to what was calculated, the method returns a string.
How can I display a returned String and a returned integer and display it on textviews?

Here is what I have:

```
 package siuc.cs.rosie;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

public class USMCISTActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    enum gender{male, female}
    private EditText pullUpArm;
    private EditText crunches;
    private EditText runMins;
    private EditText runSecs;
    private TextView factor1;
    private TextView txtscore;
    private TextView result;
    Button calculate, male, female, about;
    int tempScore;
    String tempResult;
    maleIst m;
    femaleIst f;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        m = new maleIst();
        f = new femaleIst();

        pullUpArm=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        crunches=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        runMins=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4); 

        runSecs=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        factor1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4); 
        calculate=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        male=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        female=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        txtscore=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);

        result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    }

    public void calculateScore(View v)
    {
        int armPull = Integer.parseInt(pullUpArm.getText().toString());
        int crunchesNum = Integer.parseInt(crunches.getText().toString());
        int runmins = Integer.parseInt(runMins.getText().toString());
        int runsec = Integer.parseInt(runSecs.getText().toString());
        //String resultTxt=result;
        String myresult=result.getText().toString();
        int score = Integer.parseInt(txtscore.getText().toString());//this is what is making the program crash 


        if (male.isPressed())
         {
            m.pullUp = armPull;
            m.crunchM = crunchesNum;
            m.minutes = runmins;
            m.seconds = runsec;
            score = m.mIstScore();//Something to do with (score) is what is making it crash
            myresult= m.MistState();
         }
        else if (female.isPressed())
         {
            f.arm = armPull;
            m.crunchM = crunchesNum;
            m.minutes = runmins;
            m.seconds = runsec;
            //score = f.fIstScore();
            myresult = f.FistState();
         }


        result.setText(myresult);
        result.setVisibility(1);
        //txtscore.setText(Integer.toString(score));
        txtscore.setVisibility(1);

        //result.setText(myresult);//is this right? I cannot get the result pass or fail to show

    }

    public void femaleClick(View v)
    {
        factor1.setText("Arm Hang");
    }

    public void maleClick(View v)
    {
        factor1.setText("Pull-Ups");
    }
}
```

HERE IS THE LOGCAT:

> 07-30 22:00:16.826: W/KeyCharacterMap(266): No keyboard for id 0
>
> 07-30 22:00:16.826: W/KeyCharacterMap(266): Using default keymap:
>   /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.006: D/AndroidRuntime(266): Shutting down VM
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.006: W/dalvikvm(266): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the
>   activity
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266):    at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266):    at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266):    at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266):    at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266): Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266):    at
>   siuc.cs.rosie.USMCISTActivity.calculateScore(USMCISTActivity.java:61)
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266):    at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266):    ... 11 more
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266):    at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:412)
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266):    at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:382)
>
> 07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266):    ... 15 more

Here is the rest of the classes:

MALE CLASS:

```
package siuc.cs.rosie;


public class maleIst{
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
    int pullUp;
    int pullUpScore;
    boolean pullUpState;
    int crunchM;
    int crunchScore;
    boolean crunchState;
    int s=73;
    int high=809;
    int low=800;
    int run;
    int mrunScore;
    boolean done=false;
    boolean mrunState;
    String str=new String ();

    public int getPullUp()
    {
        return pullUp;
    }
    public void setPullUp(int pullUp)
    {
        this.pullUp = pullUp;
    }
    public int getcrunchM()
    {
        return crunchM;
    }
    public void setcrunchM(int crunchM)
    {
        this.crunchM = crunchM;
    }
    public int calculatePullUp()
    {
        if (pullUp<3)
        {
            pullUpScore=0;
            pullUpState=false;
        }
        else if (pullUp>20)
        {
            pullUpScore=100;
            pullUpState=true;
        }
        else if (pullUp>=3 && pullUp<=19)
        {
            pullUpScore=pullUp*5;
            pullUpState=true;
        }

        return pullUpScore;
    }


    public boolean PullUpState()
    {
        return pullUpState;
    }


    public int calculateCrunch()
    {
        if (crunchM<44)
        {
            crunchScore=0;
            crunchState=false;
        }
        else if (crunchM>=44 && crunchM<=100)
        {
            crunchScore=crunchM;
            crunchState=true;
        }
        else if (crunchM>100)
        {
            crunchScore=100;
            crunchState=true;
        }
        return crunchScore;
    }
    public boolean CrunchState()
    {
        return crunchState;
    }
    public int calculateMRun()
    {
        int run=seconds+(minutes*60);
        while (!done)
        {
            if (run<=540)
            {
                mrunScore=100;
                done=true;
                mrunState=true;
            }
            else if (run>810)
            {
                mrunScore=0;
                done=true;
                mrunState=false;
            }
            else if (run>540 && run<550)
            {
                mrunScore=99;
                done=true;
                mrunState=true;
            }
            else if (run>=801 && run<=810)
            {
                mrunScore=73;
                done=true;
                mrunState=true;
            }
            else if (low<=run && run<=high)
            {
                mrunScore=s;
                done=true;
                mrunState=true;
            }
            else
            {
                s++;
                high-=10;
                low-=10;
                mrunState=true;

            }   
        }
        return mrunScore;
    }
    public boolean MRunState()
    {
        return mrunState;
    }
    public String MistState()
    {

         if (PullUpState()==true && CrunchState()==true && MRunState()==true)
                 str="Pass";
         else
                 str="Fail";

        return str;
    }
    public int mIstScore()
    {
        int finalScore=pullUpScore+crunchScore+mrunScore;
        return finalScore;
}}
```

FEMALE CLASS:

```
package siuc.cs.rosie;


public class femaleIst  {
    int run;
    int armScore;
    boolean armState;
    int arm;
    int crunchF;
    int crunchScore;
    boolean crunchState;
    boolean frunState;
    int s=72;
    int high=889;
    int low=880;
    int frunScore;
    boolean done=false;
    String str=new String ();
    int minutes;
    int seconds;

    public int getArmHang()
    {
        return arm;
    }
    public void setarmHang(int arm)
    {
        this.arm = arm;
    }
    public int getcrunchF()
    {
        return crunchF;
    }
    public void setcrunchF(int crunchF)
    {
        this.crunchF = crunchF;
    }

    public int calculateHang()
    {
        if(arm<12)
        {
            armScore=0;
            armState=false;
        }
        else if (12<=arm && arm<=40)
        {
            armScore=arm;
            armState=true;
        }
        else if (40<arm && arm<=69)
        {
            int temp=arm-40;
            armScore=40+(temp*2);
            armState=true;
        }
        else if (arm>=70)
        {
            armScore=100;
            armState=true;
        }
        return armScore;
    }

    public boolean hangState()
    {
        return armState;
    }
    public int calculateCrunch()
    {
        if (crunchF<44)
        {
            crunchScore=0;
            crunchState=false;
        }
        else if (crunchF>=44 && crunchF<=100)
        {
            crunchScore=crunchF;
            crunchState=true;
        }
        else if (crunchF>100)
        {
            crunchScore=100;
            crunchState=true;
        }
        return crunchScore;
    }
    public boolean CrunchState()
    {
        return crunchState;
    }

    public int calculatefRun()
    {
        int run=seconds+(minutes*60);
        while (!done)
        {
            if (run<=630)
            {
                frunScore=100;
                done=true;
                frunState=true;
            }
            else if (run>900)
            {
                frunScore=0;
                done=true;
                frunState=false;
            }
            else if (run>630 && run<640)
            {
                frunScore=99;
                done=true;
                frunState=true;
            }
            else if (run>=890 && run<=900)
            {
                frunScore=72;
                done=true;
                frunState=true;
            }
            else if (low<=run && run<=high)
            {
                frunScore=s;
                done=true;
                frunState=true;
            }
            else
            {
                s++;
                high-=10;
                low-=10;
                frunState=true;

            }

        }
        return frunScore;
    }

    public boolean FRunState()
    {
        return frunState;
    }
    public String FistState()
    {
        if (hangState()==true && CrunchState()==true && FRunState()==true)
            str="Pass";
        else
            str="Fail";

        return str;
    }


    public int fIstScore()
    {
        int finalScore=armScore+crunchScore+frunScore;
        return finalScore;
    }
   }
```

****UPDATED CODE***** FOR THE MAIN ACTIVITY****

I removed(extends Activity from the other "helper" classes)

```
public class USMCISTActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    private EditText pullUpArm;
    private EditText crunches;
    private EditText runMins;
    private EditText runSecs;
    private TextView factor1;
    private TextView txtscore;
    private TextView result;
    Button calculate, male, female, about;
    int tempScore;
    String tempResult;
    maleIst m;
    femaleIst f;
    final CheckBox checkBox=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        m = new maleIst();
        f = new femaleIst();

        pullUpArm=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        crunches=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        runMins=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4); 

        runSecs=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        factor1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4); 
        calculate=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        //final CheckBox checkBox=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        txtscore=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);

        result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    }

    public void calculateScore(View v)
    {   
        int armPull = Integer.parseInt(pullUpArm.getText().toString());
        int crunchesNum = Integer.parseInt(crunches.getText().toString());
        int runmins = Integer.parseInt(runMins.getText().toString());
        int runsec = Integer.parseInt(runSecs.getText().toString());
        String myresult="NA";
        int score=0;
        //checkBox.setChecked(false);
        //String resultTxt=result;
        //String myresult=result.getText().toString();
        //int score = Integer.parseInt(txtscore.getText().toString());


        if (checkBox.isChecked())
        {
            f.arm = armPull;
            m.crunchM = crunchesNum;
            m.minutes = runmins;
            m.seconds = runsec;
            score = f.fIstScore();
            myresult = f.FistState();

        }
        else 
        {
            m.pullUp = armPull;
            m.crunchM = crunchesNum;
            m.minutes = runmins;
            m.seconds = runsec;
            score = m.mIstScore();
            myresult= m.MistState();
        }


        result.setText(myresult);
        result.setVisibility(1);
        txtscore.setText(Integer.toString(score));
        txtscore.setVisibility(1);

        //result.setText(myresult);//is this right? I cannot get the result pass or fail to show

    }

    public void femaleClick(View v)
    {
        factor1.setText("Arm Hang");
    }


}

HERE IS MY XML LAYOUT:

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/enterScores"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/run1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:text="@string/Crunches"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:text="@string/pullUps"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="@string/seconds1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="@string/minutes1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:onClick="calculateScore"
        android:text="@string/calculate" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:onClick="femaleClick"
        android:text="@string/gender1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ega"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/egablack" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText3"
        android:text="@string/score1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText3"
        android:text="@string/testState"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>

AND FINALLY AN UPDATED LOGCAT:

07-30 21:35:44.952: D/AndroidRuntime(274): Shutting down VM

07-30 21:35:44.952: W/dalvikvm(274): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)

07-30 21:35:45.013: E/AndroidRuntime(274): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

07-30 21:35:45.013: E/AndroidRuntime(274): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{siuc.cs.rosie/siuc.cs.rosie.USMCISTActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

07-30 21:35:45.013: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
07-30 21:35:45.013: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-30 21:35:45.013: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-30 21:35:45.013: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-30 21:35:45.013: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 21:35:45.013: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-30 21:35:45.013: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-30 21:35:45.013: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 21:35:45.013: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-30 21:35:45.013: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-30 21:35:45.013: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-30 21:35:45.013: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

07-30 21:35:45.013: E/AndroidRuntime(274): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 21:35:45.013: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1637)
07-30 21:35:45.013: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at siuc.cs.rosie.USMCISTActivity.<init>(USMCISTActivity.java:27)
07-30 21:35:45.013: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-30 21:35:45.013: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
07-30 21:35:45.013: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-30 21:35:45.013: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
07-30 21:35:45.013: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  ... 11 more
07-30 21:35:47.923: I/Process(274): Sending signal. PID: 274 SIG: 9
```

Comment: what are you passing in `txtscore`?

Comment: Well the simple answer is that when this line is run...`int score = Integer.parseInt(txtscore.getText().toString());`, the `txtscore` `TextView` doesn't contain a valid number.

Comment: I need it to return an integer in score with the score, and a String in result. txtscore was to convert the textview to integer... I thought..

Answer (score 1):

```
m = new maleIst();
f = new femaleIst();
```

You can not and MUST not try to do this.

A class which extends `Activity` can never be instantiated using `new`. An `Activity` is a special case class and can only ever be created by the OS using `startActivity(...)` or the other `startXXX` methods.

An `Activity` should never expose any methods or member variables for use by any other application component - Android simply doesn't work that way.

Please read [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html) and [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) documentation.

**EDIT:** Firstly, remove `extends Activity` from your `maleIst` and `femaleIst` class definitions. They're clearly meant to be helper classes and do not provide `Activity` functionality, i.e., they don't serve as UI components.

Secondly, the exception which is crashing your app is caused by this line...

```
int score = Integer.parseInt(txtscore.getText().toString());
```

...but you're never setting any text for the `txtscore` widget. It seems to me you either need to remove this line altogether or move it to later in your code.

To be honest, I'm really not sure what your code is doing but it looks like you have a process flow issue, i.e., you're doing things in the wrong order.

Comment: How can I fix this problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: See my **EDIT** to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
07-30 22:00:22.037: E/AndroidRuntime(266): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
```

The above section of the error implies that somewhere in your code you are trying to turn an empty string into a number. I Expect that it is somewhere in either your `MistState` or `FistState` code. Could you post that?

--EDIT

Looking at your extra code it looks like the exception is thrown when a field is not completed. You are trying to cast an empty string to an integer.

Comment: It does not crash anymore! I changed all my variables from parseInt to Integer.valueOf. And that seemed to stop it. Now I can see what is returned and it shows a score of 0 and a result of Fail no matter what I enter.

Comment: txtscore=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7); this is on my onCreate, and int score=1 is on my method. There is nothing linking the two... when I try to say txtscore=score; it says that I cannot convert from a textview to an integer. I got the same thing going on with result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8); and  String myresult="NA"; it says I need to convert the textview to string. @shri046

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace it looks like the code is failing for this view

```
int score = Integer.parseInt(txtscore.getText().toString());
```

The problem might be that your TextView does not have any text set on it, hence the **getText()** is returning an empty string. This will cause the integer conversion to fail with an invalid number format exception.

Having said that, you do not need to convert the string to int at that step. Since you already have access to the TextView that will need to be set, you only need to call the **setText(...)** method on it.

Change these lines

```
String myresult=result.getText().toString();
int score = Integer.parseInt(txtscore.getText().toString());//this is what is making the program crash
```

to this

```
String myresult = "NA"; // Default text to display
int score = 0; // Default score value
```

That will basically get you past your program crashing.

Now the reason why there is no score or result (pass/fail) displayed is because you are trying to use the Button.isPressed() method to check if it is male or female.

```
if(male.isPressed()) {
......
} else if(female.isPressed()) {
......
}
```

Since you are clicking on a 'Calculate' button to get the scores, none of the other buttons will be in a pressed state. What I believe you need here is some sort of checkbox or radio control to select from male or female. Perhaps a list will do this job.

Just to do a sanity check if your calculation is working, change `if(male.isPressed())` to `if(true)`. This will always return the score for male. You can do the same for the female class as well.

Also, as noted in the above post, your subclasses do not need to extend the `Activity` class. This is of course based on the code that you have provided.

Comment: @Squonk I have erased the Activity on the helper classes, and  shri046, I initialized the score and the result. It doesn't crash anymore and now it shows 0 and NA. Now I am working on changing the buttons to checkboxes...

Comment: Hi again, I have updated code above, I added one checkbox for female, now it is back to crashing. please help!@Squonk

Comment: This is likely the issue 
`final CheckBox checkBox=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);`
You are trying to get a hold of the checkbox even before it has been created. Try moving that call inside the onCreate method.